# AJAX sorting while order value is within a variable

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Have not found anyhing on stack

My sorting method is:

```php
if($_GET['f1']=='ASC')
{
    $order = ' ORDER BY clients.name ASC ';
    $f1 = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-sm f1" id="DESC"><i class="bi bi-sort-alpha-down-alt"></i></button>';
}
elseif($_GET['f1']=='DESC')
{
    $order = ' ORDER BY clients.name DESC ';
    $f1 = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-sm f1" id="ASC"><i class="bi bi-sort-alpha-down"></i></button>';
}
else
{
    $f1 = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-sm f1" id="ASC"><i class="bi bi-sort-alpha-down"></i></button>';
}
```

The same logic I have for f2, f3 and f4

My AJAX for f1 is like:

```
$(document).on("click",".f1",function(){
    
    let id = $(this).attr('id');
    
    $.ajax({
        method:'GET',
        url:'ajax.php?x=clients',
        data:{f1:id},
        success:function(response){
            $('#data').html(response);
        }
    })
})
```

Everythign works properly but I would like to make sorting for all methods (f1,f2,f3,f4) using one ajax function

Please advise the best way to make it without total modification of any of the methods

Comment: What do the other methods do? Are they sorting by other fields, or something?

Comment: All other methods are sorting the other fields (surname,company,date)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a few small changes I think:

- Make *all* the search buttons have a single class in common, and store the type of search and the direction as data-attributes (don't use `id="ASC"` like that because IDs must be unique in a HTML document, and clearly you could end up with more than one like that, across the 4 methods).
- handle click on the single class, and fetch the data attributes of the clicked button to determine the settings to put into the AJAX call.

For example:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-sm sort" data-sort="clients" data-direction="DESC">
```

and

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-sm sort-btn" data-field="surname" data-direction="ASC">
```

Then in the JS:
.

```
$(document).on("click",".sort",function(){
    
    let direction = $(this).data('direction');
    let field = $(this).data('field');
    
    $.ajax({
        method:'GET',
        url:'ajax.php',
        data: {"field": field, "direction": direction},
        success:function(response){
            $('#data').html(response);
        }
    })
});
```

Obviously you should then amend your PHP to look for `$_GET['field'] and` $_GET['direction']`, to match the AJAX parameter names (I felt these were a lot easier to understand than "x" and "f1", which are pretty meaningless, but you may disagree and change them back if you wish).

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcard on `class`  before send data.

```
$("[class^='f']").on('click', function() {
  let id = $(this).attr('id'); //get id
  let cls = $(this).attr('class'); // get f1,f2 as class name
  // On ajax call
  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'ajax.php?x=clients',
    data: {
      cls: id
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $('#data').html(response);
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: I've changed the ajax call and above but now it is no reaction after clicking the button

Comment: `<button type="button" class="f1 btn btn-link btn-sm` means f1 class name must put in first order

Comment: Wildcard say class start with `f`

Comment: Made the corrections - still the same result. ID's are unique. Should I amend anything on the php side?

Comment: No just work around class and `console.log` is your friend. Please don't depend fully with other code, think about your code, debug , as per your question it's general advice without executable code we are unable to give you full solution. Think about that. Its idea which you try to implement.